# bootstrap carousel don't make slider

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My carousel doesn't work well carousel. I don't be which is the problem

My code in github is

https://github.com/Mangulomx/campeonato-frontend

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The index.html file

```
div class="container">
          <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="/ribbit/img/1.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="/ribbit/img/2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="/ribbit/img/3.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="/ribbit/img/4.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the left and right controls for the images.

```
<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-      slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

Those belong after your 'wrapper for slides div' end tag.

Also you need to add the link for the bootstrap css link, to make it easier just paste that in the 'head' section of your html doc.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

After that you should be good to go! I got most of the info from http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp if you want to refer to that as well.